# How to transfer tokens from metamask to myetherwallet

Tags: tokens, myetherwallet, metamask

Can't seem to find a "send tokens" button on metamask. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could just export your `metamask` account to myEtherWallet.

1. Select your account on Metamask. Click Export Private key.
2. You can copy the private key or save it to file.
3. Open MyEtherWallet --> View wallet info tab.
4. There you could access your metamask account in myEtherWallet without needing to transfer it.
5. If you wish you to transfer, you could do it from myEtherWallet to any account (including that of MyEtherWallet).